# Format error when deserializing file

Tags: c#, xml

My application connects to 2 different servers which returns a response in xml format, as string. I then deserialize the string into an object. This works fine with server 1. But it fails when I receive the xml string from server 2. The only difference in the response xml's are the `<OAR>` tag. Server1 returns the tag as `<OAR>0</OAR>` where server2 returns a null value, `<OAR/>`. When trying to deserialize this, it fails:

Extract from XML response from SERVER2

```
            <PaymentFreq>000</PaymentFreq>
            <AvailableBalance>
                <Amt>0.00</Amt>
            </AvailableBalance>
            <AcctBranch>629</AcctBranch>
            <OAR />
```

C# code:

```
            XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AccountListInqRsCIF));
            StringReader reader = new StringReader(message);
            acctListInqRs = (AccountListInqRsCIF)xs.Deserialize(reader);
```

**Exception:**

> {"Input string was not in a correct format."}
>
> "There is an error in XML document (1, 3028)."
>
> at System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options,
>   NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal)
>   at System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style,
>   NumberFormatInfo info)    at System.Xml.XmlConvert.ToInt32(String s)
>   at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAccountListInqRsCIF.Read31_AcctSummType(Boolean
>   isNullable, Boolean checkType)    at
>   Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderAccountListInqRsCIF.Read32_AcctListInqRsCIF(Boolean
>   isNullable, Boolean checkType)

Comment: What is on line 3028 of your XML file and what is your class `AccountListInqRsCIF` that you're trying to deserialize into ?

Comment: Can it be a localization issue? The xml contains the decimal dot while, due to the localization settings, the decimal coma is expected?

Comment: @FaNIX and what is your class does it accept null values there ? If possible update your question with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve it by using the Default DefaultValueAttribute:

```
[DefaultValueAttribute(0)]
public int OAR
{
    get { return this.OARField; }
    set { this.OARField = value; }
}
```